# Prime-ng multiselect filter placeholder not displaying

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using Prime ng multi select and setting the property filter as true and also adding filterPlaceholder property as below.

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1" filter="true" 
filterPlaceHolder="Search..." defaultLabel="example" >
</p-multiSelect>
```

I am not getting filter place holder inside multi select. Please help.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue even without filter option, did you find solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to write `[filterPlaceHolder]="'Search...'"`, by this you are passing `Search...` as a string in `filterPlaceHolder`

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
[filterPlaceholder]="Search..."
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried both [filterPlaceholder] and (filterPlaceholder). Its showing wrong template console error.

Comment: Strange in my case filterPlaceHolder="Search..." works fine. Can you how the error?

Answer (score 0):

`filterPlaceholder="value"` - its hardcoded value

`[filterPlaceholder]="value"` OR

```
filterPlaceholder="{{ value }}"
```

- Here value is variable with some value in ts file

You might be having another issue:
Kindly send the error in console if any.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` in all multi-property properties.

```
[filterPlaceholder]="value"
```

or

```
[filterPlaceholder]="'value'"
```

is `true`.

A list of these Properties is available [here](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect).